# Does this DFA satisfy the complement of the given language?

Tags: theory, proof, automata, computation-theory, dfa

I got this challenge:

> Given  = {  ∊ {0, 1}<sup>*</sup> : 01 is a substring of  }
>
> Show  compliment is regular.

My understanding is that a DFA for the compliment of this language would need to *reject* 01 substrings.

Here is my DFA for L(M) = L compliment:

[image: MY DFA]

Does my DFA correctly accept the compliment language?

Comment: Might be better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my bad I had no clue that was a thing, isn't stack overflow for CS in the first place? new to all this

Comment: No probs, it's considered good form to put a link back here if you ask elsewhere...

Comment: not sure if you'd be able to help with this, but I'm attempting to post the question on cs.stackexchange, however each time I click post it scrolls to the top and doesn't actually post. wasn't able to google a fix

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the other site, maybe some field isn't validating?  Maybe check up the page for errors and try and fix them...  think you solution looks about right, though if you get points for minimizing the graph, I think you could drop a state

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, except that it wouldn't accept an empty input, which to my understanding should be accepted.

With that modification there is no reason any more to distinguish between q<sub>0</sub> and q<sub>2</sub>: they can be merged into an accepted state:

[image]

Comment: Didn't think about zero length strings!  My comment about dropping the state was referencing the same transition as you noted.

Comment: Is empty input the same as lambda(empty string)?

Comment: I mean the empty string. In regular languages, the symbol λ represents a regular expression that accepts empty strings as input.

Comment: Awesome, I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!
If you wish to do so, you can also [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), but it is optional.